# Fedora: is there a way to add YUM RPM repositories without editing /etc/yum.repos.d/?

Tags: fedora, yum, rpm

On Ubuntu based systems, it is possible to add repositories through Synaptic Package Manager interface without having to edit the `sources.list` file.

Is this also possible on Fedora based systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you need this?

Many repos provide an RPM file which just drops the relevant repo meta-data directly into `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, so you just manually install that RPM and thereafter use `yum` normally.